How to move route files into route folders in React Native Expo
I have a React native expo application. According to the official documentation, pretty much every file in the /app folder is supposed to be a route. So the file app/settings.tsx would map to the settings route.
This is the folder structure of my project:

In the _layout.tsx file, I have the following code:
import { Stack } from "expo-router";

export default function RootLayout() {
    return (
        <Stack initialRouteName="settings">
            <Stack.Screen name="settings" />
            <Stack.Screen name="index" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        </Stack>
    );
}

And in the settings/index.tsx file, I have this code:
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

export default function Settings() {
    return (
        <View
            style={{
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
            }}
        >
            <Text>Edit app/settings/index.tsx to edit this screen.</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

I want to be able to have a route inside a folder so that I can keep related styles and other files organized within a route. According to the docs, this would be done using the following pattern: app/settings/index.tsx. This, however, leads to an error when I try to load the routes in the stack, saying that the route does not exist.

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I fix it so that the route does appear? Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Sorry, but I can't understand this: <Stack.Screen name="index". What does it mean? the name prop of an expo-router Stack.Screen must accept folder name which contains _layout.tsx or index.tsx. By which doc guide did you write like the above?

If you mean you want to create a settings tab and have related screens in a folder, you need to wrap settings in () so the folder name would be '(settings)' and the root layout would render it like so:


<Stack.Screen name="(settings)" options={{headerShown: false, ...}} />



And within the (settings) folder, you'll need another _layout.tsx file and then you can render your index file.


import {Stack} from "expo-router";

export type SettingStackParamList = {

  index: {
  }, 
  // any other screens can go here and you can pass parameters to them
};

export type SettingsStackNavigationType = NavigationProp<SettingStackParamList>;

const SettingsStackLayout = () => {


    return (
        <Stack>
         <Stack.Screen name="index"/>                 
        </Stack>
    )
}

export default SettingsStackLayout;



Now you can add whatever you want in your (settings) tab folder
Useful YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-shpLyYBLc&t=485s
